# How can I change a theme to set a background color to the current line in TextMate 2?

Tags: themes, textmate2

In TextMate 1, we could use the Preferences dialog for this. In TextMate 2, at least at this point, I gather we have to use Edit Bundles, and edit the source of a specific theme. But what is the syntax to set a background color to the current line (i.e. the line on which the cursor is)?

Answer (score 2):

While editing the theme files have you looked at this particular setting, just pasting a snippet from a theme I saw it in. (Havent actually tried to see if this works, sorry)

```js
settings = {
    background = '#FFFFFF';
    caret = '#000000';
    foreground = '#000000';
    invisibles = '#BFBFBF';
    lineHighlight = '#FFFBD1';
    selection = '#BDD5FC';
};
```

I am referring to the `lineHighlight` option in the settings above.

Answer (score 2):

Open up the bundle editor and then go to Theme's (or whatever theme you might have picked under View > Theme (Solarized and SubtleGradient have their own bundle).

then it is a simple JSON document for editing your theme.

Edit the "lineHighlight" property and set it to whatever you want your highlighted line to be in HEX.

Answer (score 0):

According to Macromates's Twitter [theme editor is not implemented yet](http://twitter.com/#!/macromates/status/156810808586813441).

Comment: I don't care so much about the nice UI to configure this (i.e. the theme editor), and am just looking for a way to do it. I think I'm mostly missing the syntax to set the background color of the current line, when editing the theme by hand, as a text file.